# IAd implementation in iphone apps

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm doing an iphone app. Can i implement iAds in iphone apps?. iAds integration is possible only in universal apps only? plz help me..

Comment: it may help http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_iAds_into_an_iOS_5_iPhone_App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iAd can be integrate in iPhone, iPad and Universal App, It is nothing like that 'your app should be Universal App to used iAd feature'.

When it comes to iAd, apple has following concern:

"iPhone apps running in compatibility mode on iPad will not display a test ad in development or live ads in deployed apps running in the compatibility environment. To ensure that your app is capable of displaying iAd banners for all your customers, make sure you’ve developed an app that supports all possible devices."

that's why Apple suggested to create Universal app to utilise iAd on iDevices.

Please go through with the [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app) nice blog for integrating iAd in iOS App.

OR

Follow [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/iad/resources/) and [example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) given by Apple.

Comment: But apple's document says: "Create Universal Apps                       

iPhone apps running in compatibility mode on iPad will not display a test ad in development or live ads in deployed apps running in the compatibility environment. To ensure that your app is capable of displaying iAd banners for all your customers, make sure you’ve developed an app that supports all possible devices.".

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2264/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011827  this is the link

Comment: ie Suggestion from apple that if you create only iPhone app and that app will run on iPad too but will not shown the iAd banner, it will only show iAd banner in iPhone. To support all iOS devices apple suggested developer should go for Universal App.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can implement iAds in your iPhone app.

iAd is provided by Apple and it can be used in both iPhone and iPad application. And also for Universal app.

Only ad size will be different as per the iPhone and iPad screens.

Have a good start.

Cheers!

Comment: But apple's document says: "Create Universal Apps iPhone apps running in compatibility mode on iPad will not display a test ad in development or live ads in deployed apps running in the compatibility environment. To ensure that your app is capable of displaying iAd banners for all your customers, make sure you’ve developed an app that supports all possible devices."

Comment: Actually when we implement iAds then sometimes, iAd will not display in the development mode. And only testing iAd banner will display. And when we live our app then it will display live ad on device. You can implement it for both iPhone, iPad and Universal (iPhone & iPad). Only iAd size will be differ according to screen size.